# webview local video file

Tags: android, flash, webview

First, I want specify one thing :

```
webView.loadUrl("http://mydomain.com/file.html"); // working
```

But not if it's local file like this :

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html"); // won't working
```

Html file :

```
swfobject.embedSWF("file.swf", "flashcontent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.124", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

webView .java file :

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);


webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

My manifest :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    ...
    <application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"...
```

My asset folder :

```
file .html
file .xml
file .swf
file .f4v
```

My file.swf call f4v movies but just display black screen.

Thank you a lot if you can help me !!!

EDIT : my logcat eclipse

```
09-10 10:07:29.420: E/webview(11210): registerForStylusPenEvent onAttachedToWindow
09-10 10:07:29.420: E/webview(11210): registerForStylusPenEvent START
09-10 10:07:29.425: E/webview(11210): registerForStylusPenEvent END
09-10 10:07:29.605: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11210): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-10 10:07:29.605: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11210): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: Did you see any error info on the log cat? NOt sure if f4b file could be played.

Comment: Ok I have add the logcat error

Comment: If it's cause .f4v, why my app can play movies when they are on internet (http://domain.com/file.f4v) but not when they are on my asset folder ?